# How to connect to iOS device using flutter reactive ble

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

It's been a few day I've been struggling to establish a BLE connection with an iOS device. The following code is called once a scan has successfully found the device I'm looking for, and works just fine with android devices.

```
void connect(Bike bike, BuildContext context) {
    String connectionId = ""; //foundDeviceId
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      connectionId = bike.uuid; //On iOS the device ID is a UUID
    } else {
      connectionId = bike.mac; //On Android it is a MAC address
    }
    currentConnectionStream = bluetoothProvider.flutterReactiveBle
        .connectToDevice(
      id: connectionId,
      connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 15),
    )
        .listen(
      (connectionState) {
        switch (connectionState.connectionState) {
          ...
        }
      },
      onError: (error) {
        cancelConnectionStream();
        log("ble_service error: " + (error as PlatformException).message!);
      },
    );
  }
```

When trying to connect to an iOS device, I'm prompted by this error log, forcing the `.listen()` function to jump immediately to the `OnError`:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(invalidMethodCall(method: "disconnectFromDevice", details: Optional("\"deviceID\" is invalid")), invalid "disconnectFromDevice" method call ("deviceID" is invalid), null, null)
```

I've tried setting `String connectionId` with a hardcoded value of my device UUID, upper and lower case, formatted with dashes... But still get stuck on the error message.

Has anyone faced this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few trial and errors, I figured out that in order for the `connectToDevice()` to work appropriately, you need to give the `device.id` field from the `DiscoveredDevice` that is created when scanning for devices.

```
flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices().listen((device) {
  ...
  [once device is found, cancel scan stream]
}

flutterReactiveBle.connectToDevice(id: device.id).listen() {
  ...
}
```